# why grep does not return all pari of numbers?

Tags: shell, grep

Executing `echo "123456" | grep -Eo "[[:digit:]]{1,2}"` will return tree pairs, `12`, `34`, `56`.
Why it does not return `12`, `23`, `34`, `45`, `56`?

Comment: once a character is consumed, the regex engine moves on...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your regular expression is not printing all of 5 pairs of numbers because you are asking only for three.

Your regex is the equivalent of `[0-9][0-9]` and will check that particular match starting from left; so if you have `123456` the steps would be something like:

- 1 -> Match? No; don't print anything.
- 12 -> Match? Yes; print it.
- 3 -> Match? No; don't print anything.

And so on...

Note that it doesn't start again after a match, otherwise it would match `12` over and over again...

You can use other solutions for your problem.

For example, if you need all pairs in that string you can use a function that take the first two numbers; cut the first one and check again, until the string is too short...

```
#!/bin/bash
check_pairs() {
  local str="${1}"
    if [ "${#str}" -ge 2 ]; then
      printf "%s\n" "${str}" | sed -e "s/^\([0-9][0-9]\).*$/\1/"
      check_pairs "${str#?}"
    fi  
}
check_pairs "123456"
exit 0
```

Probably there are other solutions (better, faster, stronger), but I cannot think of them right now.

Answer (score 1):

While you already have a valid answer, if your shell is `bash` (or another advanced shell that allows string indexes), it would be far more efficient to use bash's built-in *string indexing* and a C-style `for` loop to output each pair in a given string rather than spawning a separate subshell on each loop iteration created by calling `sed`.

Bash string indexing allows you to access `len` characters within a string beginning at `start` index (where the valid indexes are `0 - len-1`) using the form:

```
${var:$start:$len}
```

Combined with a C-style `for` loop looping over each index `i` in the string beginning at index `1` (the 2nd character) and outputting the pair of characters created by:

```
"${var:$((i-1)):2}"
```

A short example would be:

```
str=123456

for ((i = 1; i < ${#str}; i++)); do 
    echo "${str:$((i-1)):2}"
done
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ str=123456; \
for ((i = 1; i < ${#str}; i++)); do echo "${str:$((i-1)):2}"; done
12
23
34
45
56
```

Look things over and let me know if you have further questions.